# Mongoose typing issue with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, definitelytyped

I am building an app using mongoose and typescript. Here is a simple model I have made:

```
import * as callbackMongoose from 'mongoose';
var mongoose = callbackMongoose;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    hash: String
});

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

It works well but I need to cast each document to any before accessing properties. I read a guide that said I could do this:

```
interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  username: String;
  email: String;
  hash: String;
}

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
```

My problem is that the type mongoose doesn't seem to have the property `Document`. It also doesn't have the property `ObjectId`. When I cast mongoose to any and use these members it works just fine. It seems to be a typing issue.

I installed the mongoose typing like so:

```
npm install @types/mongoose --save
```

The typings do work for Schema and they are good for all of the other libraries I use. Is something wrong with these type definitions? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For TypeScript@2.0
I think you may use

```
npm install @types/mongoose --save
```

instead of:

```
npm install @typings/mongoose --save
```

This is full example:

**Database.ts**

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:123456@ds149437.mlab.com:49437/samples');

export { mongoose };
```

**UserData.ts**

```
import { mongoose } from './../../Services/Database';

export interface UserData {
    is_temporary: boolean;
    is_verified: boolean;
    status: boolean;
    username: string;
}

export interface IUserData extends UserData, mongoose.Document, mongoose.PassportLocalDocument { };
```

**UserModel.ts**

```
import { IUserData } from './UserData';
import { mongoose } from './../../Services/Database';

import * as passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';
import Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  password: String,
  status: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  is_verified: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  is_temporary: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

var UserModel;
try {
  // Throws an error if 'Name' hasn't been registered
  UserModel = mongoose.model('User')
} catch (e) {
  UserModel = mongoose.model<IUserData>('User', UserSchema);
}

export = UserModel;
```

I also full project example using typescript, node.js, mongoose & passport.js right here: https://github.com/thanhtruong0315/typescript-express-passportjs

Good luck.

Comment: It turns out the issue was with the fact that I assigned the import to a variable. I fixed it using an approach similar to what you described in `Database.ts` so your answer is correct. Thanks!